# Facebook api commands?

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication

Currently i have

```
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

This displays info such as:

```
    [id] => 525252252
    [name] => random name
    [first_name] => random
    [last_name] => name
    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/random.name
    [username] => random.name
```

what is the api command to display only one of these fields. For example if i only want to output the [name] field and not all the others?

I have been searching the internet for this for a while but cant seem to find it. Don't know if i am searching the correct thing.

For info i am going to echo/print the output using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just looking for `echo $user_profile['name']` but I could be misunderstanding the question - the result set is accessible the same way any multidimensional array is in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Just use this:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
echo $user_profile['name'];
```

That should work..

Comment: zerkms' answer is actually the best one. Less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name');
```

If what you need is only `name` field - it makes sense to request only it. After that you'll get the `$user_profile` array with only 2 items - `id` and `name`